# Question considered "opinion based" inquiring about objective status of software project

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

Why is this question considered opinion based?: [Project status of SUSE WebYaST](https://superuser.com/questions/1751344/)

I believe that whether an organization maintains a project is an objective matter, and I would be pleased if the  decision to close the question might be reversed.

Comment: "whether an organization maintains a project is an objective matter" only if you work for the organization. Any else is just guessing.

Comment: I disagree that working for the organization provides the only possible access to the knowledge, but the larger issue is that the limitation of acquiring certain knowledge is not the same as its being opinion based.

Comment: Why do people down vote this question without expressing any actual grievance over the question itself?

Comment: Downvotes on meta indicate that people disagree with your position, not necessarily that your question is "bad". It is likely that people agree with the closure reason.

Answer (score 2):

Whether *people* or an organisation are contributing or maintaining a thing is a problem with those people or that organisation.

We can only guess what those people are thinking, whether they believe it is still "supported" or abandoned.

Who *owns* the project is a matter of public record, you just go to the site and there it is. The owners *thoughts* on the status of the project are a matter of subjective guesswork and not able to be objectively determined without input from the owners.

The only objective information we can give is that the project was [last updated on 19 Jan 2015](https://github.com/webyast/webyast) and anything more than that is just us guessing. It seems *likely* that it is abandoned, but we cannot say with any certainty.

For me it boils down to this being a people problem and not a problem that actively involves the computer hardware or software.

Comment: I am confused. You invoke "we", as though the  question is targeted at some specific group. Like any question, its answer may not be known to many who find it, and they are free to leave it alone.  Someone not having information to serve as the basis for a solid reply to a question hardly seems to me a reason to close it. Why not leave it open, for someone who may know?